# C++ sizeof on string array not returning expected results when passed to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, runtime-error, sizeof

Trying to find the size of an array dynamically. Getting the size while in main() works fine but doesn't when i pass it to the GetSize function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string GetSize(string array[]);

int main()
{
  string array[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"};
  int ARRAY_SIZE = (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));

  cout << "Total Size: " << sizeof(array) << endl;
  cout << "Single Element Size: " << sizeof(array[0]) << endl;

  // Pass the array as an argument to GetSize()
  GetSize(array);
}

string GetSize(string array[])
{
  // Get size of the array
  int ARRAY_SIZE = (sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]));

  cout << "Size of array is: " << sizeof(array) << endl;
  cout << "Size of 1st element is: " << sizeof(array[0]);    
}
```

**Output**

```
// Total Size: 160
// Single Element Size: 32
// Size of array is: 8
// Size of 1st element is: 32
```

I have no clue why the discrepancy between the Total Size and the Size of array.

**Repl Sandbox:** https://repl.it/@phreelyfe/Size-Of-Error

Comment: There is definitely a few duplicates of this one.

Comment: i've searched stackoverflow for over an hour. none of the duplicates address passing arrays as arguments while getting sizeof

Comment: In C++ (from its C heritage), arrays are delicate soap bubbles and turn into a pointer at the drop of a hat.  In C++, use a `std::vector` instead, and avoid the problems of arrays.

Comment: Addendum: If the size is known at compile time and unchanging thereafter, prefer `std::array` to `std::vector`

Comment: @Eljay i'm still new to this and haven't worked with vector's yet. is it not as simple as passing a pointer reference and converting it in the function?

Comment: The short answer is you need to pass the number of elements to the function along with the pointer. That is if you are not permitted to use c++. if you are permitted to use c++ `std::array` is a better choice.

Comment: I'll have to go with that then. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
template <typename T, std::size_t N>
constexpr std::size_t getArrSize (const T(&)[N])
 { return N; }
```

?

I mean: different arrays, with different sizes, are different types.

So you have to explicit the size for the incoming argument.

When you write

```
string GetSize(string array[])
```

the compiler consider `string array[]` as a `string * array`, so you get `sizeof(array)` as the size of the pointer (8).

In `main()` the `sizeof(array)` is the size of the `string[5]`, so 160.

Comment: This doesn't explain "the discrepancy between the Total Size and the Size of array."

Comment: this definitely works! I'm hesitant to mark this as answer until I can find out how to fix this pointer/reference issue. I will use this for now tho. Thx!

Comment: @4UmNinja - answer improved; hope this helps

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - answer improved.

Comment: This makes sense! I'll mark this as the answer and improve my question once i implement a solution.